# Borrar un label y una entrada en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un problema en tkinter, necesito que la función de un Radiobutton ponga en la ventana un label y un entry, eso funciona. Pero necesito que si se seleccione otra opción, los borre. Si alguien me puede decir cómo lo hago le estaré agradecido.

```
#Marco recepción/despacho
        self.marco_recepcion_despacho=customtkinter.CTkFrame(marco_ticket, border_color=("black"), border_width=2)
        self.marco_recepcion_despacho.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=5, padx=5, columnspan=2)
        def destino():
            if radio.get() == 1:
                pass
            if radio.get() == 2:
                label_destino=customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.marco_recepcion_despacho, text="Despacho :")
                label_destino.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
                entry_destino=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.marco_recepcion_despacho)
                entry_destino.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
            
                
        radio=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.radio1=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(self.marco_recepcion_despacho, text="Recepción", variable=radio, value=1, command=destino)
        self.radio2=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(self.marco_recepcion_despacho, text="Despacho", variable=radio, value=2, command=destino)
        self.radio1.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.radio2.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
```

Comment: No conozco a customtkinter, pero probaste usar widget.grid_forget() en los widgets a ocultar? Ese metodo hace que tkinter "olvide" la ubicacion del widget. Eso si, tendras que reubicarlo cuando sea necesario. Por cierto, por que no creas los widgets solamente al inicio y luego tu funcion unicamente hace el trabajo de mostrar u ocultarel frame. Tal y como esta hecho, se crean nuevos widgets al cohete cada vez que el usuario elige esa opcion.

Comment: Lo cambi{e como dijiste y funcionó mejor, muchas gracias Dante.

Comment: De nada Carlos c:

Comment: cierra la pregunta

Comment: Es realmente necesario? muchas veces he encontrado respuestas en preguntas de otras personas.